# Chained jQuery promises with abort

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise

I'm currently writing API code which, several layers deep, wraps $.ajax() calls.

One requirement is that the user must be able to cancel any request (if it's taking too long, for example).

Normally this is accomplished via something simple, like:

```
var jqXHR = $.ajax(..);
$(mycancelitem).click(function () {
     jqXHR.abort();
});
```

However my code looks more like this:

```
function myapicall() {

    var jqxhr = $.ajax(…);
    var prms = def.then(function (result) {
        // modify the result here
        return result + 5;
    });

    return prms;
}
```

The problem here is someone calling `myapicall()` only gets a jQuery.Promise with no way to abort it. And while the sample above is very simple, in my actual code there are several layers of chaining, in many places.

**Is there a solution to this?**

Comment: `myapicall()` returns the jqXHR object.  Why wouldn't `var api = myapicall();  api.abort();` work?  Also, I don't think your `return result + 5;` does anything.

Comment: the line def = def.then(...) means it's a chained promise. if you try it in code, you'll see what you get back is not a jqXHR, but rather a real jQuery.Promise, without abort. it doesn't return the jqXHR from the ajax request, but the chained promise.

Comment: Ah!  I didn't notice that.  What if you removed the `def=` before `def.then()`?  Would that work?

Comment: I would instead return an object that contains two properties, one that is a function that when executed, aborts the request, and a second that contains the promise object.

Comment: A solution would be to use a [proper Promise library](http://promisesaplus.com/) that does support *cancellation*  and can assimilate jQuery deferreds. Unfortunately, I can't name one yet; but maybe you have more luck at searching.

Comment: Hi @automaton, any news with this question? I stumbled at same problem

Comment: @Strajk unfortunately the answer is that JS/jQuery has no proper promise model, so it's not possible. in the end, I didn't provide the ability to cancel XHR requests...

Answer (score 4):

My solution inspired from all the

### With jQuery promises

client.js

```
var self = this;
function search() {
  if (self.xhr && self.xhr.state() === 'pending') self.xhr.abort();
  var self.xhr = api.flights(params); // Store xhr request for possibility to abort it in next search() call
  self.xhr.then(function(res) {
    // Show results
  });
}
// repeatedly call search()
```

api.js

```
var deferred = new $.Deferred();
var xhr = $.ajax({ });
xhr.then(function (res) { // Important, do not assign and call .then on same line
  var processed = processResponse(res);
  deferred.resolve(processed);
});
var promise = deferred.promise();
promise.abort = function() {
  xhr.abort();
  deferred.reject();
};
return promise;
```

### With Q + jQuery promises

client.js

```
var self = this;
function search() {
  if (self.xhr && self.xhr.isPending()) self.xhr.abort();
  var self.xhr = api.flights(params); // Store xhr request for possibility to abort it in next search() call
  self.xhr.then(function(res) {
    // Show results
  });
}
// repeatedly call search()
```

api.js

```
var deferred = Q.defer();
var xhr = $.ajax({ });
xhr.then(function (res) { // Important, do not assign and call .then on same line
  var processed = processResponse(res);
  deferred.resolve(processed);
});
deferred.promise.abort = function() {
  xhr.abort();
  deferred.reject();
};
return deferred.promise;
```

Answer (score 3):

you could return a object that has both the jqXHR and promise

```
function myapicall() {

    var jqXHR = $.ajax(..);
    var promise = jqXHR.then(function (result) {
        // modify the result here
        return result + 5;
    });

    return {jqXHR:jqXHR,promise:promise};
}
```

Comment: ideally yes, this is what I would do. however, as I mentioned in my original question, unfortunately the calls span several layers, different files, etc. so I would have to update every call chain to start returning this object instead of just a promise, which isn't really feasible

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you have you make your own promise which will represent the entire operation and add a special abort function to it. Something like the following:

```
function myapicall() {
    var currentAjax = $.ajax({ ... })
        .then(function(data) {
            ...
            return currentAjax = $.ajax({ ... });
        },
        function(reason) { wrapper.reject(reason); })
        .then(...)
        .then(...)
        .then(...)
        .then(...)
        .then(...)
        .then(...)
        .then(...)
        .then(...)
        .then(...)
        .then(...)
        .then(function(data) {
            ...
            wrapper.resolve(data);
        },
        function(reason) { wrapper.reject(reason); });

    // haven't used jQuery promises, not sure if this is right
    var wrapper = new $.Deferred();
    wrapper.promise.abort = function() {
        currentAjax.abort();
        wrapper.reject('aborted');
    };
    return wrapper.promise;
}
```

This pattern (updating the `currentAjax` variable) must be continued at each stage of the `$.ajax` chain. In the last AJAX call, where everything has finally been loaded, you will resolve the wrapper promise with whatever data you wish.

Answer (score 1):

Looked for solution to similar problem and solved it like this:

```
var xhr = $.ajax({ });
return xhr.then(function (res) { 
  var processed = processResponse(res);
  return $.Deferred().resolve(processed).promise();
}).promise(xhr);            // this is it. Extends xhr with new promise
```

This will return standard jqXHR object with abort and such + all promise functions.

Note that you may or may not want to return .promise(xhr) from .then() as well. Depends on how you want to treat response in .done() functions from API.

Comment: Interesting approach, but very confusing. I would not rely on this to continue working in the future.

Comment: This is actually a really neat solution, with jQuery as it stands. The code can be simplified by removing the Deferred from the `.then()` callback and returning `processResponse(res)`, which is then free to be either synch or async - ie to return either a promise or a value.

Comment: It will be interesting to see if jQuery manages to retain its `.promise(obj)` capability when they go to v3.

Answer (score 0):

I worked around this using a set of three helpers. It's pretty much manual and you must pay attention to really not forget to use the helpers in your API's implementation, or else well... abort won't abort.

```
function abort(prom) {
    if( prom["abort"] ) {
        prom["abort"]();
    } else {
        throw new Error("Not abortable");
    }
}

function transfer_abort_from_one(abortable, other) {
    other["abort"] = function() { abortable.abort() };
}

function transfer_abort_from_many(abortables, other) {
    other["abort"] = function() {
        for(let p of abortables) {
            if(p["abort"]) {
                p["abort"]();
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Now

```
function api_call() {
    let xhr = $.ajax(...);
    let def = $.Deferred();
    // along these lines
    xhr.fail( def.reject );
    xhr.done( def.resolve );
    // then
    let prom = def.promise();
    transfer_abort_from_one(xhr, prom);
    return prom;
}


function api_call2() {
    let xhrs = [$.ajax(...), $.ajax(...)];
    let prom = $.when.apply(null, xhrs);
    transfer_abort_from_many(xhrs, prom);
    return prom;
}
```

Using your API and aborting:

```
var api_prom = api_call();
abort(api_prom);

var api_prom2 = api_call2();
abort(api_prom2);
```

Note that depending on how your API is built, you must not forget to transfer the abort from the lower layers promises to the higher layer promises. All this is error-prone. It would be a lot better if JQuery (for example) did the transfer when  `when()` or `then()` get called.